How do we know what elements molecules consist of?
I have have a very fundemental question about chemistry. I am curious about the methods used to determine what elements molecules consist of, and how we know that these methods work. For example, how do we know that methane consists of one carbon bonded to four hydrogens, and not  something completely different, or that oxygen gas consists of two oxygen atoms?
I am sure the methods used are different depending on the type of compound being analyzed, but I am moreso asking for reading resources where I can start reading. Since I am quite new to chemistry, I don't know where to start looking. I was hoping someone here could give me some resources or references.
Thanks in advance!

Does it look like we live in XIX century? They sure had some trouble with things like that, but it was two hundred years ago.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22270/how-was-the-diatomic-nature-of-many-common-gaseous-elements-originally-determine https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/771/how-were-elements-and-molecular-formul%c3%a6-determined-in-the-old-days https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34048/can-molecular-structure-be-determined-without-modern-characterization-methods https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/14875/how-can-i-determine-the-chemical-composition-of-local-rocks-and-minerals

There is an entire branch of chemistry dedicated to your query. It is called analytical chemistry (and now called measurement sciences in a fancier way).
In the nineteenth and early twentieth century, the analytical chemist had only 2-3 tools, an accurate balance, titration vessels, and a flame spectroscope. With that, those chemists produced marvelous results, accurately measured atomic masses and one even earned a Nobel Prize.
Today we need million dollar laboratory facilities because the molecules and their related questions have become way more complex. Instead of methane, the problem is to analyze big molecules like proteins. It is not about elements only, there is a big deal as to how those elements are arranged in space.
Also remember that chemists rarely analyze a complete unknown. For example, if someone brings a piece of chocolate and asks to analyze all the components, this will take at least a year because thousands of compounds are present!

For example, how do we know that methane consists of one carbon bonded
to four hydrogens

Because someone has done an extensive chemical analysis ages ago. Someone must have estimated the density of the gas, and predicted the molecular weight. Someone must have done an extensive combustion analysis to show that only carbon dioxide and water are present after combustion, so the starting material has only carbon and hydrogen. From the weight of the two products, we know the ratio of carbon to hydrogen, 1:4!

Here's an overview article.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elemental_analysis
You will have to follow the links and look at other articles (and ideally non-Wiki sources as well) if you want more details of what analytical method does what and how those choices differ for different types of molecules.
As a practical matter, usually you sort of know what you started from and then can verify what you got.  Like for methane, you can directly react carbon and hydrogen and verify the stoichiometry of the compound is CH4.  After that, knowing the molecule's properties (molecular weight, fp, bp, IR spectra fingerprint, etc.) it is pretty easy to then label fractions of methane, even in mixed streams (for example in natural gas wells, refining processes, etc.).  It's not like someone takes a flask of CH4 and then goes and repeats the "what's in it" derivations, much, now, in practice.  Instead you can fingerprint versus known properties.
